# How does a website detect my location over VPN with not IPv6/DNS/WebRTC leak?

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, ipv6, geolocation

a website like this
https://findmylocation.org/

can detect my location when I explicitly allow my browser to detect my location. the goal is to even if I allow location in browser, the website shouldn't be able to detect my real location as I'm using VPN, on a PC, with no GPS and using personal WiFi router that isn't tied to any specific location (DSL connection).

so, I'm using VPN and on this WebRTC test, I see the VPN's IP address.
https://www.expressvpn.com/webrtc-leak-test

also, on extended DNS leak test I see DNS server(s) from different countries that belong to the VPN server's country location, not even my own country.
https://www.dnsleaktest.com/

IPv6 test from here says no leaks
https://ipv6leak.com/

so what and how is this website detecting my location? I expect when I allow location for that website, it detect my location based on my VPN's IP location, not my real location.

my VPN uses UDP protocol, and also VPN client has firewall/kill switch feature, no untunneled connection is allowed.

I use 3rd party cookie blocking in browser, and that website has never saved any cookies on this browser before, I made sure of that, used inPrivate browsing mode too.

Location is turned off in Windows settings and its history cleared.

websites, not just the one I mentioned above, can geo-locate me when I allow it in browser, to the exact street and house, so it's not because of the timezone of my computer or installed fonts, computer languages etc. those would only narrow it down to country, but this is very precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't actually prevented your browser from calling Windows' geolocation APIs.

When you allow your browser to geolocate you, it calls your OS's geolocation APIs, which often do a Wi-Fi scan and take note of the BSSIDs (wireless MAC addresses) of all Wi-Fi APs (wireless routers) in range, including your neighbors. It then sends that list off to its online geolocation service which knows the reasonably exact locations of those APs. So the service is able to locate you based on it knowing the location of the APs around you.

Note that there are many different geolocation services that know the locations of all APs, including privately owned home wireless routers. Smartphones with GPS do Wi-Fi scans and send off the BSSIDs with their GPS location to the geolocation services to keep the services up to date.

Try plugging in via an Ethernet cable and completely powering down your Wi-Fi card, then reboot and try again.

Comment: Can we access that online location and find out locations of Mac addresses ?